# Count how many values in some cells of a row are not NA (in R)

Tags: r, dplyr

I've got a data frame with lots of columns. For each row of the data frame, I'd like to get a count of how many columns are NA. The problem is that I'm only interested in a few of the columns, and want to (efficiently) call those columns out.

Using mutate the way I do in the fake sample below gives me the right answer.

```
library(stringr)

df  <- data_frame(
         id = 1:10
       , name = fruit[1:10]
       , word1 = c(words[1:5],NA,words[7:10])
       , word2 = words[11:20]
       , word3 = c(NA,NA,NA,words[25],NA,NA,words[32],NA,NA,words[65])
    ) %>%
    mutate(
        n_words = 
            as.numeric(!is.na(word1)) + 
            as.numeric(!is.na(word2)) + 
            as.numeric(!is.na(word3)) 
    )
```

However, it's painful to type and read even for a toy example like this--when I have more than 3 columns to count, it's largely useless. Is there a more R/dplyr-y way to write this, maybe using `select()` style syntax (eg. `n_words = !count_blank(word1:word3)`)?

I considered using `summarize()` sans grouping, however, I need the data in the columns I'm counting and if I add them to `group_by`, I'm in the same boat of calling out nearly all columns again.

Comment: Try `rowSums(is.na(df[startsWith(names(df), "word")]))`, But I am confused. You state *"I'd like to get a count of how many columns are NA"* but call the column `word_count`.  Do you want the count of NAs or non-NAs?

Comment: `rowSums(!is.na(df[startsWith(names(df), "word")]))` instead

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use `is.na()` over the selected columns, then `rowSums()` the result:

```
library(stringr)
df <- data_frame(
  id = 1:10
  , name = fruit[1:10]
  , word1 = c(words[1:5],NA,words[7:10])
  , word2 = words[11:20]
  , word3 = c(NA,NA,NA,words[25],NA,NA,words[32],NA,NA,words[65]))

df$word_count <- rowSums( !is.na( df [,3:5]))

df
      id         name    word1     word2   word3 n_words
   <int>        <chr>    <chr>     <chr>   <chr>   <dbl>
1      1        apple        a    actual    <NA>       2
2      2      apricot     able       add    <NA>       2
3      3      avocado    about   address    <NA>       2
4      4       banana absolute     admit   agree       3
5      5  bell pepper   accept advertise    <NA>       2
6      6     bilberry     <NA>    affect    <NA>       1
7      7   blackberry  achieve    afford alright       3
8      8 blackcurrant   across     after    <NA>       2
9      9 blood orange      act afternoon    <NA>       2
10    10    blueberry   active     again   awful       3
```

### Edit

Using `dplyr` you could do this:

```
df %>% 
    select(3:5) %>% 
    is.na %>% 
    `!` %>% 
    rowSums
```

Comment: I like how this solution doesn't depend on regex-ing (which isn't the real issue--all bets are off if the column names will be named something consistent). Is there any way to get this in a dplyr chain, though?

Answer (score 4):

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

df  <- data_frame(
  id = 1:10
  , name = fruit[1:10]
  , word1 = c(words[1:5],NA,words[7:10])
  , word2 = words[11:20]
  , word3 = c(NA,NA,NA,words[25],NA,NA,words[32],NA,NA,words[65])
) 

library(purrr)
# Rowwise sum of NAs
df %>% by_row(~ sum(is.na(.)), .collate = 'cols')

# Rowwise sum of non-NAs for word columns
df %>% 
  select(starts_with('word')) %>% 
  by_row(~ sum(!is.na(.)), .collate = 'cols')
```

Comment: for anyone reading this more recently, purrr::by_row() has been removed.

Comment: But dplyr has gained `rowwise` if you want to perform similar approaches

Comment: While deprecated from purrr, the by_row function is now in the purrrlyr package which contains a few functions described as "at the intersection of dplyr and purrr".

Comment: I tried to use `df %>% rowwise() %>% mutate(n_notNA = sum(!is.na(c_across())))` with a dataset containing mixed types of columns and got the error message "Error: Problem with 'mutate()' input 'n_notNA'. x Can't combine 'xxx' <character> and 'yyy' <numeric>." It seems that c_across() cannot handle mixed types of columns. How to correct my code?

Comment: Try something like this: `... mutate(n_notNA = sum(!is.na(c_across(where(is.numeric))))` or use another [tidyselect syntax](https://tidyselect.r-lib.org/articles/syntax.html)

Answer (score 1):

Another `dplyr` solution:

```
library(stringr)

## define count function

count_na <- function(x) sum(!is.na(x))

df$count_na <- df %>%

  select(starts_with("word")) %>%

    apply(., 1, count_na)

## A tibble: 10 × 6
      id         name    word1     word2   word3 n_words
   <int>        <chr>    <chr>     <chr>   <chr>   <int>
1      1        apple        a    actual    <NA>       2
2      2      apricot     able       add    <NA>       2
3      3      avocado    about   address    <NA>       2
4      4       banana absolute     admit   agree       3
5      5  bell pepper   accept advertise    <NA>       2
6      6     bilberry     <NA>    affect    <NA>       1
7      7   blackberry  achieve    afford alright       3
8      8 blackcurrant   across     after    <NA>       2
9      9 blood orange      act afternoon    <NA>       2
10    10    blueberry   active     again   awful       3
```