# Counting non-empy cells per row in RStudio

Tags: r

I am trying to investigate international cooperation in a specific research area. For that, I have generated a dataframe that contains publication data 2018 - 1998 in the EU, together with the respective research institutions. Now I want to get the percentage of international institutions per publication but need to get [no. institutions EU]/[total institutions]. I need a count for the total institutions per row but have really no idea on how to do this.

My data kinda looks like this:

```
2018 Inst.A,Spain    Inst.B,UK    Inst.C, Belgium
2018 Inst.C, Germany Inst.D,UK,   Inst.E, Belgium
2018 Inst.F, Germany Inst.A,Spain Inst.B, UK
.
.
.
```

So far I have tried to use

```
df[,75] <- rowSums(df == "Country A")
```

but did not get any output. 
I am very new to R and Rstudio. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Possible duplicate / related: [*Count how many values in some cells of a row are not NA*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39648111/2204410)

Answer (score 0):

What does your data set look like? Is it just a list of institutions?  Something like this code might work ...

```
library(dplyr)
institutions <- c('A','A','B','B','B','B','B','C')
df <- data.frame(institutions)
count(df, institutions)
```

Comment: I have 1963 rows for the publications and up to 74 colums for the institutions that are or were part of the respective work. There are also a lot of empty cells since not many publications have that many institutes working on the same paper

Comment: Might be good to post some sample data.  Your data set seems small ... can't you do this in an Excel pivot table?

Comment: I edited it to show some data :)
The thing is that I need to count the existance of the country per row and I can't get this to work...
No, I need to do this in R, my university requires me to...