# Count values per rows in a data frame R

Tags: r

I know, there is other questions like this one but none of them answer my specific problem.

On my data frame, I need to count the number of values in each rows between cols 3 and 8.

I want a simple `NB.VAL` like in Excel..

```
base_graphs$NB <- rowSums(!is.na(base_graphs)) # with this code, I count all values except NAs but I can't select specific columns
```

How to create this new column "`NB`" on my data frame "`base_graphs`" ?

Comment: Possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39648111/count-how-many-values-in-some-cells-of-a-row-are-not-na-in-r

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You were really close:

```
base_graphs$NB <- rowSums(!is.na(base_graphs[, 3:8]))
```

The `[, 3:8]` subsets and selects columns 3 through 8.

Comment: Thank you, there is so multiple way for every purposes :)

Answer (score 0):

`apply` can apply a function to each row of a data frame. Try:

```r
base_graphs$NB <- apply(base_graphs[3:8], 1, function (x) sum(is.na(x)))
```

Comment: Thank you, it works but I have the number of NAs. So I put an "!" before is.na and it's fine.